# iOS didLaunchWithOptions with Background Location Updates

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have an application that needs to receive CoreLocation Visit updates whenever the system fires them off when the app is in the foreground, background or has been terminated. I start the tracking while the app is in the foreground with a UI switch. I have the background location capability activated as well. I am getting Visits information in the background fairly reliably, but after a few days or if the device runs many other "heavy" applications the application seems to crash. It seems like I need to be able to restart the app after the system has killed it off.

```
class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

static let locationInstance = LocationService()
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


func startTracking() {
    notifications()
    locationManager.delegate = LocationService.locationInstance
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringVisits()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
}
```

I cannot figure out how to receive visit updates even after, for example, the system terminated the app from the background. I understand that the appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in the app delegate should be activated in the background, but I am not sure that:
a) I have setup everything I need to be getting these notifications
b) I am not sure how to handle the launchOptions Dictionary if I do get the notification. 
c) Do I need to call startMonitoringVisits() again from the didEnterBackground portion of the app delegate?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with those locations? If the app is terminated then it can only be started by user or by push notifications(can be a silent notification).

Comment: I just need to be able to get the coordinates from the visit object